# Spring Security: Authentication user manually

Tags: authentication, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I trying  authenticate user in Spring Security application via oAuth. I'm already received token and user's data.

How can I authenticate user manually without password and classic login form?
Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Authentication authentication =  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person, null, person.getAuthorities());
log.debug("Logging in with {}", authentication.getPrincipal());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Where `person` is your UserDetailsBean object.

Comment: Please note that this will work only if your signIn path uses security mapping of following type `<s:intercept-url pattern="/signin/**" access="" />`  In the newer versions of spring security there is a better and faster way of skipping security for eg. `<s:http security="none" pattern="/assets/**"/>` with the new format the given solution will not work as there is no SecurityContextHolder created in later scenario.